# Can I use the CountIf function to count the # of cells containing certain date keywords?

Tags: excel, date

I have a set of data that looks something like this:

11/8/12 5:20

11/7/12 15:57

11/7/12 13:51

11/7/12 10:47

11/7/12 8:00

Just in Excel, I want to be able to count the number of rows with 11/8/12, and the number of rows beginning in 11/7, etc. I have a pretty long list of dates and times, but I'm only interested in the dates.

I tried =COUNTIF(A1:A235, "<11/8/12 5:20") to get everything before 11/8, but obviously this doesn't work because I need to type in the time. Does anyone know how to:

1) make the timestamp irrelevant?
2) somehow search for rows that "contain" a certain date value and count up the rows that contain that value?

Comment: If these entries are dates then just `=COUNTIF(A1:A235, "<11/8/12")`

Answer (score 3):

You can insert in a cell e.g. F7 the date which should be used
and then your formula will look like this

```
=COUNTIF(E8:E12;"<"&F7)
```

And then in case that your *F7* will contain `11/7/12 14:00` the *countif* will return 3

*NOTE: expecting the british date 11/7/12 is dd/mm/yy*

EDIT: Date function

When I've seen another answer, I would like to show another approach, which is culture safe. Whenever we will put some strings representing dates, it could happen that a collague has different regional settings *(e.g. British dd/mm/yy vs US mm/dd/yy)*

That's why I placed the `date` into separated cell, representing the Date regardless of the culture. If that all have to be placed inside one cell, the correct approach is to use Date function

```
=COUNTIF(E8:E12;"<"&DATE(2012;7;11)+TIME(14;0;0))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Excel dates are integers and the time is a fractional value so you can simply count between one date and the next (date +1) to get everything on a single date, e.g. for everything on 11/7

`=COUNTIF(A1:A235, ">=11/7/12")-COUNTIF(A1:A235, ">="&"11/7/12"+1)`

or in Excel 2007 or later you can use COUNTIFS

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A235, ">=11/7/12",A1:A235,"<"&"11/7/12"+1)`

for either one you can use a cell reference with the date as Radim suggests, i.e. with date in B1

`=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$235,">="&B1,A$1:A$235,"<"&B1+1)`

With that last version you can simply list all your dates in B1 down, and then use the formula in C1 copied down to get counts for each date